# How to append a number to the end of an array?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a Mx1 matrix and I want to plot it with a (M-1)x1 matrix. To make this possible, I want to pad the second matrix with zeros so that its dimensions become equal to the first. How can I append a number to the end of the array?

Answer (score 2):

or you can append directly using keyword `end`

```
a(end+1) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Put differently: In order not to introduce non-existing data, you can exclude the final, "unmatched" element from the other larger matrix (or vectors as in your example). As long as you know that you are missing the final element from `z`:

```
scatter(x(1:end-1), y(1:end-1), 5, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for starts:
`a=[1,2,3]`
`a=[a,4]`

Comment: The first line creates an array called `a` with the elements `[1,2,3]`. The second appends the element `4`, so that `a` will be `[1,2,3,4]`. You should be able to use this idea in your code to append a zero to one of your datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution to be the most applicable to your scenario of padding out a matrix. This will change A to a 10x10 matrix with all the other values padded out to zero.

```
A = [1 5 3 8 9 4 7 6 5 2];
A(numel(A), numel(A)) = 0;
```